# Find and copy last file - 1 in a directory in date format yyymmdd

Tags: java, arrays, wildcard

I have a directory where log txt files are logged. Each log file has the following title date format 20180114.log, which is yyymmdd.log

I want to get a copy of the preceding file (date) so if the current date file is 20180114.log, I want to get a copy of the 20180113.log, and then make a copy of it (give may be the same name with extension _copy)

I am using the below code to make a list all the files of the extension *log in ascending order and it works. the output is as follow:

20180116.LOG
20180117.LOG
20180118.LOG

Now I need to get a copy of the last file - 1 - (last_entry - 1) and make a copy of it. Could anyone please help with this using the code below:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class search
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

String WILD_CARD = "";
 List <File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>();
   File folder = new File("d:\\");
   File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if(WILD_CARD!=null) {  
        Pattern wildCardPattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+WILD_CARD+"
(.*)?.log",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        for(File file: listOfFiles) {
            java.util.regex.Matcher match
wildCardPattern.matcher(file.getName());
            while(match.find()){
                String fileMatch = match.group();
                if(file.getName().equals(fileMatch))  {
                    fileList.add(file); // doesn't work
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        fileList = new LinkedList<File>( 
Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));

    for (File f: fileList) System.out.println(f.getName());
}

}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple :  use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for instance :

```
String previousFile = null;
String dateFromFileString = null;
// ...

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");


dateFromFileString = dateFormat.format(new Date()); // ex "20180114"; 

Date parsedDate;
try {
    parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFromFileString);
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(parsedDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);

    previousFile = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) ;

} catch (ParseException e) {
    //logger.log(e);
}
```

Now that you've got the previous file name, get the file and check it [exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) then copy it where you want it :

```
File prevLogFile = new File(dir, previousFile  + ".log");
if (prevLogFile.exists()) {
     // copy file 
     // see link
     Path source = ...
     Path newdir = ...
     Files.copy(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName());
}
```

See [Files#copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) for more detail on how to copy

Comment: Thanks. the yyyymmdd changes dynamically on a daily basis and new file is created everyday. I was thinking to use something like this to get the last file in the list and then - 1, (the list is in ascending order) but its not working
Object item = (((Deque<File>) fileList).getLast()-1);
System.out.println(item);

Comment: Edited : to use current date cf. dateFormat.format(new Date());